# Value does not fall within the expected range NAudio WasapiCapture

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

When I run NAudio WPF Demo Application, I want to record multiple microphone inputs from mixer using Wasapicapture. When I click Record I get this MessageBox:

[image: 1]

I followed debugger and expeption is thrown by this line of code
**audioClientInterface.Initialize(shareMode, streamFlags, bufferDuration, periodicity, waveFormat, ref audioSessionGuid);** in NAudio.Wasapi/CoreAudioApi/AudioClient.cs file.

Using Audacity Wasapi interface I can record multiple channels with this device.

Can some help why I get this error message using NAudio?

I tried several combinations for Share Mode/Sample Rate/PCM, but the result was same.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are using a supported wave format? List of supported formats for different share modes are different. Try to write your own application with Wasapi capture, and use this code for get supported formats:

```
    private List<WaveFormat> GetSupportedFormats(MMDevice device, AudioClientShareMode shareMode)
    {
        List<WaveFormat> supportedFormats = new List<WaveFormat>();

        foreach (WaveFormatExtensible format in WaveFormatsManager.PossibleFormats)
        {
            // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/device-formats
            //
            // Some device drivers will report that they support a 1-channel or 2-channel PCM format 
            // if the format is specified by a stand-alone WAVEFORMATEX structure, 
            // but will reject the same format if it is specified by a WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE structure. 
            // To obtain reliable results from these drivers, exclusive-mode applications should call 
            // IsFormatSupported twice for each 1-channel or 2-channel PCM format - 
            // one call should use a stand-alone WAVEFORMATEX structure to specify the format, 
            // and the other call should use a WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE structure to specify the same format.

            // Here we test WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE
            if (device.AudioClient.IsFormatSupported(shareMode, format))
            {
                supportedFormats.Add(format);
            }
            // Here we test WAVEFORMATEX
            else
            {
                // format.ToStandardWaveFormat() was not working with Digidesign MBox-2 for some reason
                // when converting 48 kHz 32 bit int format
                WaveFormat simpleFormat = new WaveFormat(format.SampleRate, format.BitsPerSample, format.Channels);
                if (device.AudioClient.IsFormatSupported(shareMode, simpleFormat))
                {
                    supportedFormats.Add(simpleFormat);
                }
            }
        }
        supportedFormats.Reverse();
        return supportedFormats;
    }
```

After use for WasapiCapture combinations with AudioClientShareMode and formats list